# Vertical scroll doesn't work in some applications on a Dell inspiron 14R

Tags: 12.04, touchpad

I just installed ubuntu 12.04 and installed all the necessary updates and Gnome Shell.
I have ticked "enable horizontal  scrolling" and "edge scrolling" in touchpad settings.

The scrolling works well in browsers and music players.

But the touchpad (vertical) scroll doesn't work in some specific apps. 
(System monitor and File Manager are one of them) 
Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: OP hasn't signed on in ~5 years. 12.04 is EOL and this question has no answers. VTC as `not reproducible`.